# I have created one config.xml file in eclipse. The content in that file is getting highlighted in red stating premature end of file and 1 changed line

Tags: xml

I am getting error after creating an xml file in eclipse. The error showing is in the content in that file which is getting highlighted in red and the errors stating premature end of file and 1 changed line

Comment: Please, take some time to read [how to ask](/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.